Next-auth response redirecting to localhost
I have been trying to debug this since a while now but I can't can somwone help me with this. Here I am using next-auth the route just keeps on redirecting to dashboard causing error.
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    const token=await getToken({req:request, raw:true})
    console.log('middleware executing')
    const url=request.nextUrl
    if(token && 
        (
            url.pathname.startsWith('/sign-in') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/sign-up') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/verify') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/') 
        )
    ){
        console.log('redirecting')
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard',request.url))
    }
    if(!token && url.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/sign-in',request.url))
    }

    return NextResponse.next()
}

Not sure what is wrong with this. In console I can see middleware executing and redirecting many times. Here is the config.
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/sign-in',
    '/sign-up',
    '/',
    '/dashboard/:path*',
    '/verify/:path*'
  ]
  
}

I tired debugging it many times. And I want it to redirect to dashboard once and not causing an error

This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times. Try deleting your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS


On this if statement
if(token && 
    (
        url.pathname.startsWith('/sign-in') ||
        url.pathname.startsWith('/sign-up') ||
        url.pathname.startsWith('/verify') ||
        url.pathname.startsWith('/') 
    )
)

The last condition will always be true, because all pathnames starts with "/", so every route is redirecting to dashboard, including dashboard itself.
Try to remove that line

Yup thanks! it worked
